# Unity3D on Ubuntu 19.10 with vscode and C# extension : get an error and the autocomplete doesn't working

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm a web developer (symfony <3 ;) C# and microsoft technologies are new for me ! ) and during the covid containment I want create a simple game with the game engine unity

On **Ubuntu 19.10**, I downloaded **unity Hub v2.3.0** (https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download)

From unity hub, I installed **unity3D v2019.3.7f1** (the lastest stable) with some options (**Linux & WebGL & windows build support**)

[image]

And I created a simple 2D game

[image]

All works like a charm, I can open my project and run my new game without any error in the unity3D console

From Unity, when I create a c# script, the file can be opened by my (very simple) text editor gedit. Now I want to install the cross-os IDE visualcode thanks thats I'll get some usefull extensions and autocompletion code when I'll edit my unity scripts.

So, I installed vscode via `apt install` (I followed this official guide : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)

My version of vscode is :

[image]

After some web search, I understand I must install the .NET framework (maybe I'm wrong ?)

[image]

My dotnet version (from a terminal : dotnet --version) is 3.1.201

Next I configured the unity parameter for change the default text editor :

[image]

- External Script Editor : code

  - code refer to the path /usr/bin/code, the executable of vscode
- External Script Editor Args : "$(ProjectPath)" -g "$(File)":$(Line):$(Column)

  - value by default, I changed nothing

I created a simple c# script from unity, I opened the file and vscode opened automatically (yeah !). And from vscode I added two public variables (the bool 'a' and the Rigidbody2D 'b')

[image]

I saved my script and go to unity app, the variables a and b are visible on the interface :

[image]

All works ! 
But now, I want have the autocomplete code from vscode. So, I installed the vscode c# extensions. But when the installation finished, this message appears :

[image]

The whole of log is :

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 4/2/2020, 8:10:51 PM
    Target: /home/okli/UnityProjects/SampleGame/SampleGame.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: /home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/run
    PID: 15372

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
    Starting OmniSharp on ubuntu 19.10 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
    DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
    Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
        1: StandAlone 16.4 - "/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
    MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.dll'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
    Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.4 - "/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
        CscToolExe = csc.exe
        MSBuildToolsPath = /home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin
        CscToolPath = /home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
        BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
        MSBuildExtensionsPath = /home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
    Detecting Cake files in '/home/okli/UnityProjects/SampleGame'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
    Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
    Detecting projects in '/home/okli/UnityProjects/SampleGame/SampleGame.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
    Queue project update for '/home/okli/UnityProjects/SampleGame/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
    Detecting CSX files in '/home/okli/UnityProjects/SampleGame'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
    Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
    Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
    Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
    Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
    Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.EditorConfigWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 200
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
    Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
    Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/okli/UnityProjects/SampleGame' on host 14406.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
    Loading project: /home/okli/UnityProjects/SampleGame/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Animation.Runtime.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.2D.PixelPerfect.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.VSCode.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.2D.SpriteShape.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Path.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'UnityEngine.UI.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Animation.Triangle.Runtime.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'PsdPlugin.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.CollabProxy.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.Rider.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.Mathematics.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Psdimporter.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.InternalAPIEngineBridge.001.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Sprite.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Common.Runtime.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Tilemap.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.2D.SpriteShape.Runtime.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.2D.PixelPerfect.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Animation.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.Mathematics.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.TextMeshPro.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Common.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'Unity.InternalAPIEditorBridge.001.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The referenced project 'UnityEditor.UI.csproj' does not exist.
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
    Failed to load project file '/home/okli/UnityProjects/SampleGame/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
/home/okli/UnityProjects/SampleGame/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Animation.Runtime.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.PixelPerfect.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.VSCode.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.SpriteShape.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Path.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'UnityEngine.UI.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Animation.Triangle.Runtime.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'PsdPlugin.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.CollabProxy.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.Rider.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.Mathematics.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Psdimporter.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.InternalAPIEngineBridge.001.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Sprite.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Common.Runtime.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Tilemap.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.SpriteShape.Runtime.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.PixelPerfect.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Animation.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.Mathematics.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.TextMeshPro.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Common.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.InternalAPIEditorBridge.001.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1870,5): Error: The referenced project 'UnityEditor.UI.csproj' does not exist.
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1193,5): Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
    Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /home/okli/UnityProjects/SampleGame/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
```

Something seems does not work... However, I can modify and save my c# script (add a new public var by example, the variable is added in the unity interface), but the autocomplete code does not work, when I type `public Rigidbod` and press `ctrl + space` there isn't any autocomplete help displayed.

I am unfamiliar with C# / vscode / microsoft technologies, I prefer ask here If I forget something and/or did something wrong before try (bads) solutions

Thanks for some help !

EDIT : I just notified this error on the unity3D interface

[image]

I'll do some search about this error...

**EDIT after 0xBFE1A8 answer :**

- I created a new project 'plop'
- In the UnityEditor, I changed the Visual Studio Code Editor version to 1.1.3 and click on 'Update 1.1.3' button

the error doesn't disappears, so I continued :

- I modified the "com.unity.ide.vscode" to 1.1.3 in "Packages/manifest.json"
- In the UnityEditor, the "Generate all .csproj files" checkbox is checked
- And then, I click on 'Reimport All' in the menu Assets

After all of that, the autocomplete code in vsecode does not work but the error log is smaller :

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 4/5/2020, 6:56:52 PM
    Target: /home/okli/UnityProjects/plop/plop.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: /home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/run
    PID: 30149

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
    Starting OmniSharp on ubuntu 19.10 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
    DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
    Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
        1: StandAlone 16.4 - "/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
    MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.dll'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
    Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.4 - "/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
        CscToolExe = csc.exe
        MSBuildToolsPath = /home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin
        CscToolPath = /home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
        BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
        MSBuildExtensionsPath = /home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
    Detecting Cake files in '/home/okli/UnityProjects/plop'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
    Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
    Detecting projects in '/home/okli/UnityProjects/plop/plop.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
    Queue project update for '/home/okli/UnityProjects/plop/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
    Detecting CSX files in '/home/okli/UnityProjects/plop'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
    Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
    Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
    Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
    Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
    Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.EditorConfigWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 200
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
    Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
    Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/okli/UnityProjects/plop' on host 30017.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
    Loading project: /home/okli/UnityProjects/plop/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
    The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
    Failed to load project file '/home/okli/UnityProjects/plop/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
/home/okli/UnityProjects/plop/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1193,5): Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
    Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /home/okli/UnityProjects/plop/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warnings is a known [Visual Studio Code Editor 1.1.4 bug](https://forum.unity.com/threads/visual-studio-code-editor-1-1-4-error-the-referenced-project-does-not-exist.806628/).
According to [this information](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/89835), it's **Omnisharp** extension that is causing the error:

> This issue is caused by an extension, please file it with the
>   repository (or contact) the extension has linked in its overview in VS
>   Code or the marketplace for VS Code. See also our issue reporting
>   guidelines.
>
> Happy Coding!

For me, downgrading to version **1.1.3** of the package fixed the problems.

In **UnityEditor** go to: **[Window]->[Package manager]->[Visual Studio Code Editor]->: Select 1.1.3 version and click to "Update 1.1.3" Button.**

[image]

If the errors don't go away after that:

- 1) Changed *"com.unity.ide.vscode": "1.1.3"* in *"Packages/manifest.json"*
- 2) In **UnityEditor** go to: **[Edit]->[Preferences]->[External Tools]:** Set "*Generate all .csproj files*" CheckBox to true.
- 3) In **UnityEditor** go to:[Assets]->[Reimport All]

Some people say that, if you downgrade to **1.1.3** and right after upgrade to **1.2.0** errors should be fixed, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: thank you for your detailed help :) I created a new project and I follows all your steps, le error log is smaller but I keep the error "Failed to load project file '/home/okli/UnityProjects/plop/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'." ... "/home/okli/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.16/.omnisharp/1.34.15/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1193,5): Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget...". I'll update the main post

Comment: What is your mono version?

Comment: I have the version 5.18.0.240 (detailed output here : https://i.ibb.co/9NGqhW3/Screenshot-from-2020-04-05-19-52-04.png ). I installed mono via a simple `sudo apt install mono-devel` (https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/)

Comment: Try to update to the [latest stable version](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/).

Comment: Its good ! the mono version has the problem :D 
the autocomplete works like a charm, thank you for your help and your patience ;)

Answer (score 2):

so I found a fix that works for me.  The omnisharp website (https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode) said something about, on linux, you need to set Use Global Mono for Omnisharp to 'never'.  The default is 'auto'

Instead, I was able to fix this error by setting Use Global Mono to 'always', and it seems to be working.  I no longer get errors, and intellisense is working.

Also, fwiw, I already have mono and dotnet installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but had no relation to the MonoVersion. Downgrading to **1.1.3** and *Generating the csproj* files did the job. I found it odd because this error is related to the **1.1.4** version and started to investigate further for **1.2.1** of the vscode extension. The problem was in the `sln` file and I found a simple solution.

In **UnityEditor** go to: **[Edit]->[Preferences]->[External Tools]**: Click on checkbox to *Generate .csproj files for: Embedded packages*, then on *Regenerate project files* button to solve the autocompletion issue.

[image]

It added some lines to the sln file, and autocomplete now works without needing to downgrade the extension.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I checked all those boxes for good measure, and it fixed the issue. But your answer pointed me in the right direction, and it might even work with just checking "Embedded packages". thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the vscode unity auto complete are not working, install an older version of the c# extensio, by clicking in the configuration button