# Unity 3d v2019.4.2f1 VSCode autocompletion not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Its been only 2-3 days I have started working with unity , and now it is turning really irritating for me to live without autocompletion in Vscode I have tried each and everything avilable on github issues and stack overflow still nothing is working for me

**OS Version - Ubuntu 18.04

Unity Version - 2019.4.2f1

Dotnet Version - 3.1.301

VSCode Version - 1.46.1

Mono Version -> 6.10.0.104

C# Extension Version -> 1.22.1**

Everyhting seems to be fully updated

I read this answer on Stack
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998457/unity3d-on-ubuntu-19-10-with-vscode-and-c-sharp-extension-get-an-error-and-the#)

And tried downgrading my Visual Studio Code Editor extension in Unity Package Manager to 1.13 form 1.21 but that didnt helped me out and intellisenced still didnt worked even after reimporting packages and reloading VSCODE

It would be reall helpful if someone could help me out
I also tried Changing the API compatibility level to both 2.0 and 4.x as mentioned in 1 issue on github

[image]

[image]

I also tried making new project and see if auto completion works but still nothing worked

Comment: Close editor. Delete all `*.csproj` and `*.sln` files. Start editor again.

Comment: I tried that I even tried creating a new project , no error logs but still it is not even able to detect methods in another scripts

Answer (score 0):

You need to install some extentions in vscode like:
1.Unity code snippets
2.Unity snippets
3.Unity tools
4.Debugger for unity(optional)

Answer (score 0):

This is for windows, but it might help

- Make sure the `C# extention` in `VSCode` is uninstalled
- Kill any `VSCode` process using the `Task Manager` (ctrl+shift+esc in Windows)
- Install the `dotnet SDK` from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download
- Locate your `dotnet` using `where.exe dotnet` command in a `cmd`
- Add the address that you get to the system `path`. follow [this link](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Under%20the%20%E2%80%9CSystem%20Variables%E2%80%9D%20section,also%20edit%20or%20reorder%20them.)
- Reboot your device
- In `VSCode`, install `C# extention`
- In Unity -> edit -> preferences -> external tools, set `External Script Editor` to `Visual Studio Code`
- Hit `Regenerate Project Files` button
- Now open a script file from inside Unity and see if it's fixed